# iPhone grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

Hi I'm new in iPhone programming, I'm looking for someone who can give me a tutorial on how to create a grouped TableView style please, if you can post an example with the .h and .m files, that will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set it up as you would a regular tableView.  If you are using Interface Builder, you can change the style there.  Or if you are creating it programmatically, you can set `initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped`, which gives you the desired look.

[Here is a good tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/) to help you get started if you are unfamiliar with creating a tableView in general

Comment: No problem.  Hopefully that helps you get going in the right direction =]

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple example on the Apple Developer Site called [TheElements](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007419) which shows how to set the different styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to iOS I strongly suggest you check out the stanford course [Developing Apps for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/cs193p-student-final-projects/id395605774?i=90218598). Section 10 talks about TableView.